# How should my Nop instruction and CI port be connected to my internal circuit for my control unit so that it works properly?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

[image]

I would like to see a connection example for the Nop instruction below and Ci port so that my internal circuit for my control unit is correct? Below my circuit is an example of the instruction set.
[image]

Comment: Your graphic for the control unit is too blurry to be read.  In the logic schematic, you have marked output C as Ci.  Do you distinguish between these two names in some manner?

Comment: your logic diagram has at least one term that is connected to some inputs, but not connected to any outputs

Comment: The output port c is ci I have just corrected the naming of the port.

Comment: The instruction Nop that I have labeled I am trying to understand where the connections for it should be made along with ci?